# if/else if/ else phone bill calculator C++

Tags: c++

I am having trouble coding a phone bill program in my c++ class. The problem is within my mess of  if, else if, and else statements. I looked through the forums as well as other programs on stackoverflow similar to mine but could  not understand where my errors are.  My professor is not the greatest at explaining things, and I have been teaching myself so far through the textbook.I know this is a very amateur problem but here it goes.

The purpose of the program is to practice interactive input, mathematical operations, “if … else” and “if else if” chain .

You are asked to enter a number (1-3) for a phone plan. Phone plan options are below..

```
Available Phone Plans:
1.  Ultimate    Unlimited talk and data     Unlimited Text      $75.00
2.  Deluxe      Unlimited talk, 3 GB data   550 Text messages   $55.00  
3.  Basic       Unlimited talk, 1 GB data   250 Text messages   $35.00
```

For plan 2 and 3, there will be a charge of $0.20 (20 cents) for each additional text message.

These are my made variables..

```
string customerName, phoneNumber, planType;
int planChoice, textMessages;
float planCost, overTextTotal, untaxedTotal, taxedTotalDeduction, 
          taxedTotalBill, stateFeeDeduction, federalFeeDeduction;
float overTextFee = .20;
const float STATEFEE = .05;
const float FEDERALFEE = .02;
```

And these are the calculations
// Calculations

```
untaxedTotal = planCost + overTextTotal;
stateFeeDeduction = untaxedTotal * STATEFEE;
federalFeeDeduction = untaxedTotal * FEDERALFEE;
taxedTotalBill = untaxedTotal + stateFeeDeduction + federalFeeDeduction;


cout<<"\n\tEnter 1 - 3 For Plan Type: "; 
cin >> planChoice;
cout<<"\nEnter Number Of Text Messages Used For The Month: "; 
cin >> textMessages;



if(planChoice == 1 )
{
    planType = "Ultimate";
    planCost =  75.00;
    overTextTotal = 0;  

}
else if(planChoice == 2)
{   
    planType = "Deluxe";
}
     if( textMessages <= 550)
    {
        planType = "Deluxe";
        planCost = 55.00;
    }
    else
    {
        planCost = 55.00;
        overTextTotal = ((textMessages - 550 ) * overTextFee);
     }

if (planChoice == 3)
        {
          planType = "Basic";
         }
            if (textMessages <= 250)
            {
                planCost = 35.00;
            }
            else
            {
                planCost = 35.00;
                overTextTotal = ((textMessages - 250 ) * overTextFee);
            }
```

what my question is how can I arrange my if, else if, and else statements to run properly in my output.

Comment: "how can I arrange my if, else if, and else statements to run properly in my output." ... what does that mean ??

Comment: Step through your code in your debugger and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your if-else statement with this one:

```
if(planChoice == 1 )
{
    planType = "Ultimate";
    planCost =  75.00;
    overTextTotal = 0;  
}
else if(planChoice == 2)
{   
    planType = "Deluxe";

    if( textMessages <= 550)
    {
        planType = "Deluxe";
        planCost = 55.00;
    }
    else
    {
        planCost = 55.00;
        overTextTotal = ((textMessages - 550 ) * overTextFee);
    }
}
else if (planChoice == 3)
{
    planType = "Basic";

    if (textMessages <= 250)
    {
        planCost = 35.00;
    }
    else
    {
        planCost = 35.00;
        overTextTotal = ((textMessages - 250 ) * overTextFee);
    }    
 }
```

Explanation: Your original code did not wrap the inner `if-else` statements in the upper `else if` and `else` curly braces.

Comment: And maybe, for the love of Knuth, use proper code formatting? 90% of beginner programming problems can be solved with proper readability conventions.